# C++ Inserting String into another String at specific position

Tags: c++

I have a custom String class that I've built. I'm trying to build a custom insert function that inserts a string into a specified position.

For Example:

```
String str("test");
str.insert(2, "animal");
```

would return:

```
"tesanimalt"
```

What i have so far:

```
String& String::insert(int pos, const String& str) {
   char newString[100];
   strncpy(newString, chars, pos);
   newString[pos] = '\0';
   strcat(newString, str.chars);
   strcat(newString, chars + pos);
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Um, bad news: you forgot to include your question in the question. Fancy giving it a quick edit? Thanks ever so.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with the code, one of which is that your `String` doesn’t seem to contain any actual storage.  You instead allocate a local array as a temporary variable, then let it be discarded.

It’s not possible to fix this without a MCVE, as we cannot see how `String` is supposed to work.  There seems to be some kind of member called `chars`, and you probably want to copy to that.  However, if it contains a buffer allocated with `malloc()` or `new[]`, you might, if *m* is the length of the enclosing string, and *n* the length of the intercalated string, and you insert at position *i*:

1. Reallocate the buffer of the destination string to its new size (The sum of the sizes of the two strings without their terminating nulls, plus one byte for a terminating null).  Alternatively, allocate a new buffer and copy the first *i* elements of the enclosing string.
2. Shift elements *i* through *n* of the enclosing string *n* elements to the right of the resized buffer.
3. Copy the string to insert to positions *i* through *i*+*n*-1.
4. Write a terminating null to position *m*+*n*.
5. Since you appear to want to modify the enclosing string, if you created a new buffer, deallocate the old one.  If you reallocated the buffer, set `chars` to the possibly-changed value.

Comment: Too complicated. OP can fix the issue with one `strcpy` local string chars to `chars` back before return.

Comment: @S.M. Not really.  The code would still have several other issues, such as the lack of any bounds checking. Also, the question doesn’t say whether `chars` is dynamically-allocated, or if so, how. Also, that approach would be less efficient.

Comment: @S.M. Thanks a ton! I added the following line "strcpy(chars, newString);" and the code is working correctly.

Comment: @Jon Glad you got it working, but I do strongly suggest that you always, always, always check your bounds whenever you copy to or from an array in C or C++. At the very least, use `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()`.

Comment: @S.M.: Please do not ask other Stack Overflow colleagues "Are you blind?" (ref your deleted post)